# Как добавить запись в имеющийся json файл

Tags: java, json

Не совсем понимаю как в уже в имеющийся json файл добавить дополнительную запись, чтобы не было ошибки.

Конкретнее опишу ситуацию. Создается набор данных который сохраняется в json. Через некоторое время данные дополняются и их нужно сохранить в этот же json файл. Добавить получается, но в json  файле получается так , что он ожидает конец файла, а вместо этого идет наша новая запись.

> `{"car":[{"id":"auto"}]}{"car":[{"id":"auto"},{"id":"auto2"}]}`

В моменте где у нас `}{` он ожидает конец файла

Comment: Переписывайте файл полностью, а не добавляйте в него новый JSON.

Comment: То есть, мне надо считать из него все данные и записать их снова вместе с новыми?

Comment: Не знаю насчет считывания, похоже они у Вас и так есть в памяти.